# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251

Tags: php, css, laravel-5.4

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Creative - Bootstrap 3 Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="author" content="GeeksLabs">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Creative, Dashboard, Admin, Template, Theme, Bootstrap, Responsive, Retina, Minimal">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">

    <title>welcome</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>

  <body class="login-img3-body">

    <div class="container">

      <form class="login-form" action="{{ route('login') }}"> 
       {{ csrf_field() }} 

        <div class="login-wrap">
            <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
              <input type="text" name="Username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#"> Forgot Password?</a></span>
            </label>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Signup</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    <div class="text-right">
            <div class="credits">

                <a href="https://facebook.com/D.prakash.pokhrel/"> Developer::prakash</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Its my blade file ,but it cant work properly how can i do it  workable ?? i think it problem on  action="{{ route('login') }} when i click login bottom it shows 
***Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251:*** How can i solve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `method='post'`, I hope you have declared the route correctly in `routes.php`

`Route::post('/post-form', 'YourController@saveDataFunction');` declare the route properly, if the method is `GET` write it as `Route::GET` else this would work fine.

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` clearly means the route is not found, means it's missing in the collection `OR` you declared it differently.

Comment: Thanks boss :) you are awesome

Comment: i had a Route::get instead of a Route::post as correctly mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify `method` attribute `GET` is assumed. This exception means that `Laravel` couldnot find the specified route.

Which in your case appears to be that you have declared a `post` route in your `routes/web.php` file.

Either, edit your `web.php` file **OR** specify a `method="post"` attribute on your form.